# How can I have an id set for each individual answer so that when I click on an answer it matches its id and updates `answerIsHeld` state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a simple React.js Quiz App

`App.jsx` :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react' 
import './App.css' 
import QuestionList from './components/QuestionList' 
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

export default function App() {

const [quizComplete, setQuizComplete] = useState(false)
const [questionsBunch, setQuestionsBunch] = useState([])
const [answersDetails, setAnswersDetails] = useState([])

const shuffle = (array) => {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }
  return array;
};

const getQuestionsData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&type=multiple')
    const questionsData = await res.json()
    setQuestionsBunch(questionsData.results.map((questionItem, index) => {
      let options = [
        decodeString(questionItem.correct_answer), 
        ...questionItem.incorrect_answers.map(a => decodeString(a))
      ]
      shuffle(options)
      return {
        questionId: nanoid(),
        question: decodeString(questionItem.question),
        correctAnswer: questionItem.correct_answer,
        answers: {
          options: [...options],
          answerId: nanoid()
        }
      }
    }))
}

const newAnswersDetails = () => {
  setAnswersDetails(questionsBunch.map((questionBunch) => {
    return {
      question: questionBunch.question,
      answerIsHeld: false,
      answerValidity: false,
      options: questionBunch.answers
    }
  }))
}

const decodeString = str => {
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea')
  textArea.innerHTML = str
  return textArea.value
}

useEffect(() => {
  getQuestionsData()
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
  newAnswersDetails()
}, [questionsBunch])

console.log(answersDetails)

const holdAnswer = id => {
  console.log(id)
}

const checkAnswers = () => {
  if(answersDetails.every(answerDetails => answerDetails.answerIsHeld)){
    setQuizComplete(true)
  }

  !quizComplete && getQuestionsData()
  
}
  
  return (
    <>
        <QuestionList 
          questionsBunch={questionsBunch} 
          checkAnswers={checkAnswers}
          quizComplete={quizComplete}
          answersDetails={answersDetails}
          holdAnswer={holdAnswer}
        />
    </>
  )
}
```

`QuestionList.jsx` :

```
import React from 'react'
import Question from './Question'

export default function QuestionList(props) {
    return(
        <div className="question-bank">
             {props.questionsBunch.map(questionBunch => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <Question 
                            questionBunch={questionBunch} 
                            key={questionBunch.id}
                            answersDetails={props.answersDetails}             
                            holdAnswer={props.holdAnswer}

                        />
                    </>
                )
             })}
             <div className={props.quizComplete && "quiz-check-complete"}>
                <p className='answer-count'>{props.quizComplete ? `You scored 5/5 correct answers` : ' '}</p>
                <button className={props.quizComplete ? "quiz-btn-complete" : "quiz-btn"} onClick={props.checkAnswers}>{props.quizComplete ? "Play Again" : "Check Answers"}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`Question.jsx` :

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Question(props) {
    const answerStyles = () => {

        let bg
        props.answersDetails.map(answerDetails => {
            answerDetails.answerIsHeld ? bg = 'lightgray' : bg = 'transparent'
        })

        return {
            backgroundColor: bg
        }
        
    }

    return(
        <div className='question' key={props.questionBunch.id}>
            <p className="question-header">{props.questionBunch.question}</p>
            <div className="answers" key={props.questionBunch.id}>
                {props.questionBunch.answers.options.map(option => {
                    return(
                        <div 
                            className="answer" 
                            style={answerStyles()}
                            onClick={() => {
                                console.log(option.answerId)
                            }}
                        >
                            <p className="answer-text">{option}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
            <hr></hr>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I know that `answerId` is probably not linked properly with each individual answer, but what I tried before (I don't have the code) was giving the same question id on each answer of each question. So the four answers of each question had the same id when I clicked on each.

I just don't know how to render out the answers efficiently while at the same time keeping track of id's and that each question is associated with its answers.

I'm just trying to get the unique id of every single answer when I click on it console logged for now so that I'm then able to hold an answer if its clicked, switch between answers on the same question with state, choosing an answer for each question and then checking answers at the end.